# How to set JVM parameter

Tags: parameters, jvm

Can somebody please let me know how do I set a JVM parameter in linux?

I need to set this one:

"-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true"

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "java -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true the.java.Program"?

Answer (score 2):

Just at the beginning of the java line.

```
java -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -cp foo.jar:bar.jar arg1 arg2
```